# touchesBegan in static tableView not being called

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, touchesbegan

I have read several posts here about same problem, but could not understood them mostly because I am quite new in IOS development and I use swift. Also I couldn't even found a definition for term "subclassing", maybe it is obj-c only?

Anyway, I have a tableview controller with static cells, and a textfield in one cell. I need to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps on a different area while editing the textfield. After reading posts here, I changed my touchesBegan content as following :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.nextResponder()?.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

I still don't get the touches in tableviewcontroller which is defined as :

```
class addNew: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a tapGestureRecognizer on top of you tableview.
Connect the tapGestureRecgonizer to a function/method.
Within that method, check if the textfield, is the firstresponder. If yes, then ask the textfield to resign first responder.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on Swift 4 just to endEditing and hiding the keyboard with touchesBegan. I couldn't find a way around at first.

These two steps worked for me :

1. To add gesture recogniser to table view in :

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard)))
   }
   ```
2. Ending editing in two ways in

   ```
   @objc func hideKeyboard() {
     view.endEditing(true)  
     //textField.resignFirstResponder()  /* This line also worked fine for me */
   }
   ```